# 'Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer::render: Unable to render template "error";

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to implement the tutorial given at [Zf2Tutotrial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html). But i am getting **Unable to render template "error"** the below mentioned error.

Here is my code.

```
<?php

return array(
 'controllers' => array(
     'invokables' => array(
         'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
     ),
 ),

     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
 'router' => array(
     'routes' => array(
         'album' => array(
             'type'    => 'segment',
             'options' => array(
                 'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                 'constraints' => array(
                     'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                     'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                 ),
                 'defaults' => array(
                     'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                     'action'     => 'index',
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),
 ),

'view_manager' => array(
     'template_path_stack' => array(
         'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
     ),
 ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused by the fact that your application runs into an `Exception` or `Error` of some kind but is unable to render the error since can't find templates for those.

To solve this try to add template config lines for errors like this to your `view_manager` array:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'not_found_template' => 'error/404',
    'exception_template' => 'error/index',
    ...,
    'template_map' => array(
        'error/404' => __DIR__ . '/../view/album/error/404.phtml',
        'error/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/album/error/index.phtml',
    ),
),
```

And of course make sure those templates actually map to an existing template using the template_map.

Comment: Hi Wilt, Thanks for the reply. I updated the code as per your suggestion. I get **Unable to render template "error/index"** error. I have placed the templates under module\Album\view\error.

Comment: I added some extra info to my answer. Also check your `view_manager` config array inside other modules. You might have already template configs somewhere else in your application (for example in `module.config.php` in your `Application` module.